# Объединить несколько полей с одинаковыми значениями только с помощью MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Как с помощью MySql объединить в одну ячейку похожие значения из разных ячеек и всех строк?
Например

```
id_cat | name    |id_product
_______|_________|__________
19     |Пшеница  |    5
4      |Молоко   |    5
19     |Пшеница  |    5
```

Получить вот такой результат

```
Name            | id_product
________________|____________
Пшеница, Молоко |     5
```

Тоисть нужно объединить все похожие name у которых одинаковые id_product в одну строчку через запятую без повторений названий.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашей ситуации можно использовать конструкцию `group_concat`:

```
select group_concat(distinct name) as names, id_product
    from products1
    group by id_product;
```

[Тут пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ac246/1)

Comment: Большое спасибо, все работает.